# Hbase 0.98 import table is not working

Tags: java, database, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have successfully exported a table in hbase version 0.98 using the following command (Using MapReduce API)

./hbase -Dhbase.export.version=0.98 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export testtable file:///home/test/test/hbase-0.98.4-hadoop2/bin/2

It created a folder in name '**2**' with the map reduce data of parts and success are being generated successfully and when i open the parts-000 file that has the data of the testtable.

But I try to import using import command,

./hbase -Dhbase.import.version=0.98 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import testtable file:///home/test/test/hbase-0.98.4-hadoop2/bin/2

It **successfully runs**,

**Output:**

2015-04-10 09:50:18,429 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapreduce.TableOutputFormat: **Created table instance for testtable**
2015-04-10 09:50:18,446 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
2015-04-10 09:50:18,453 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.MapTask: Processing split: file:/home/test/test/hbase-0.98.4-hadoop2/bin/2/part-m-00000:0+907
2015-04-10 09:50:18,504 DEBUG [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapreduce.Import: No configured filter class, accepting all keyvalues.
2015-04-10 09:50:18,507 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=1200000 watcher=attempt_local1700239962_0001_m_000000_0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
2015-04-10 09:50:18,509 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Process identifier=attempt_local1700239962_0001_m_000000_0 connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=localhost:2181
2015-04-10 09:50:18,509 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0-SendThread(localhost:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-04-10 09:50:18,511 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0-SendThread(localhost:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, initiating session
2015-04-10 09:50:18,520 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0-SendThread(localhost:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, sessionid = 0x14c73d562cc0043, negotiated timeout = 1200000
2015-04-10 09:50:18,532 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x14c73d562cc0043 closed
2015-04-10 09:50:18,532 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0-EventThread] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
2015-04-10 09:50:18,568 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
2015-04-10 09:50:19,080 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local1700239962_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
2015-04-10 09:50:19,096 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.LocalJobRunner: map
2015-04-10 09:50:19,096 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local1700239962_0001_m_000000_0' done.
2015-04-10 09:50:19,096 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local1700239962_0001_m_000000_0
2015-04-10 09:50:19,097 INFO  [Thread-32] mapred.LocalJobRunner: Map task executor complete.
2015-04-10 09:50:19,170 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1700239962_0001 running in uber mode : false
2015-04-10 09:50:19,172 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
2015-04-10 09:50:19,174 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1700239962_0001 completed successfully
2015-04-10 09:50:19,195 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job: Counters: 23
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=20250927
        FILE: Number of bytes written=20680389
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=2
        Map output records=2
        Input split bytes=126
        Spilled Records=0
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=0
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=252706816
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=923
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=0
2015-04-10 09:50:19,195 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local1700239962_0001
2015-04-10 09:50:19,195 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1700239962_0001 running in uber mode : false
2015-04-10 09:50:19,196 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
2015-04-10 09:50:19,196 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1700239962_0001 completed successfully
2015-04-10 09:50:19,200 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job: Counters: 23
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=20250927
        FILE: Number of bytes written=20680389
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=2
        Map output records=2
        Input split bytes=126
        Spilled Records=0
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=0
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=252706816
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=923
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=0

BUT THE testtable doesnot have any entries in it!

What the mistake am making here,, Is there any other way of doing an export and import.

Regards,
Harry

Comment: Is this your full output log? By the way your `export` and `import` commands, exports and imports with data for me.

Comment: Export is working, where as import is not working rajesh

Comment: Is there any other way to export and import the hbase table?? Do u have the hbase code for export and import??

Comment: Look into this: http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_export

Comment: I did the same thing, It is not working... Attached the logs too... Any other way is available for export and import...

Comment: Create a new table in HBase and then try to import into that table. Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

First create a new Hbase table and then run the `Import` utility.

Credit goes to [Rajesh N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3282335/rajesh-n)'s suggestion !